# How do I use CanPlaceOn or other tags to make a block placeable only on 1 block type?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was using the /give command in Minecraft 1.16.5 and wrote out `/give @s minecraft:wither_rose{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Custom Name\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:netherrack"]}`. What I wanted it to do is make the block placeable on only netherrack, not dirt or grass blocks or anything like that. I then tried to place it on netherrack and it worked, but when I right clicked with it in my hand on a grass block, it also placed.

Comment: I believe the syntax for CanPlaceOn has changed since 1.12 or 1.13, if you're trying to figure it out in 1.14 or higher. So far it's either been removed, or has been changed in a way that nobody knows how to do so. Sorry that this won't solve your problem; I've wanted to have CanPlaceOn as well.

Comment: Was your game mode "adventure" when you tested it?

Comment: Wait a minute, I had to be in adventure mode?

Comment: Yep, I'm stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in adventure mode for `CanPlaceOn` to work.